# RStudio viewer in external browser Issues in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: rstudio, dygraphs

I have one Ubuntu14.04 laptops,
when I run below with RStudio Viewer, it work fines.

```
> library(dygraphs)
> dygraph(ldeaths, main = "All", group = "lung-deaths")
```

After I set below options to run in external browser,

```
options("viewer"=NULL)
dygraph(ldeaths, main = "All", group = "lung-deaths")
```

The browser will open files with below URL but nothing show:
http://localhost:18186/session/viewhtmla4c45554fcb/index.html

If I do the same thing in R console

```
library(dygraphs)
dygraph(ldeaths, main = "All", group = "lung-deaths")
```

it work fine and will open with URL with  `file:///tmp/RtmpE7nROm/viewhtmlf371b65fc2c/index.html`

Questions1: Why Rstudio will open "http://localhost:18186..." instead of "file://....."?

Questions2: What commands in Rstudio to revert the display show in Viewer again? Currently I have to quit Rstudio and restart to get show in Viewer again.

PS: I doesn't see this issue in another Linux Labtops, not sure what configuration will causing this, hope someone can help to answer!

Below are sessionInfo() show in RStudio

```
 sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=zh_TW.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=zh_TW.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=zh_TW.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_TW.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dygraphs_0.4.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] htmlwidgets_0.5  zoo_1.7-12       magrittr_1.5     htmltools_0.2.6  tools_3.2.2      xts_0.9-7       
 [7] rstudioapi_0.3.1 yaml_2.1.13      grid_3.2.2       jsonlite_0.9.16  digest_0.6.8     lattice_0.20-33
```

Comment: I find a way to let it work for ext browser.  When I read  options("browser") in RStudio, it show Below
options("browser") 
$browser
function (url) 
{
    .Call(.rs.routines$rs_browseURL, url)
}
<environment: 0x354dc48>  
And When I do in R console 
> options("browser")
$browser
[1] "xdg-open"
So I do this in RStudio:  options("browser"="xdg-open")
 Then it work!!
But for some reason, with this settings, if I set back to view in Rstudio, options("viewer"= "rstudio:viewer") 
Now RStudio Viewer not work~ it is quite strange!!

Comment: For some reason, My Rstudio viewer now not work and display nothing,  it show below after click in viewer->Inspect.     Failed to load resource: Connection refused http://localhost:28203/session/viewhtml10cc3d879e00/index.html?viewer_pane=1